# Cocos2D-Game-UIViewController-CCScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

am new buddie to Cocos2D….am doing one very small game for that i required below one , can any one tell me please….

I have created one class which is derived from **UIViewController** with **Xib** this is my main window and one ” Play button” is here…when I press the “Play button” i want to , switch to another class which is derived from **CCScene** and vice versa……

Thanks Beforehand !

Answer (score 2):

You'll find UIKit + Cocos2D examples in the [source code for my Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/). One example project in the Chapter 15 folder shows you how you can switch between 3 scenes by pressing a regular UIKit button, and how to start and stop Cocos2D entirely.